# How to connect to a device with previously set static IP that's now on a different subnet?

Tags: networking, router, ip, subnet, camera

I have a PoE camera that has a static IP address that was manually set on the camera interface. The IP address is 192.168.86.x, but now my new router has a different subnet (192.168.0.x). All of my other devices have adjusted as expected with the router handling DHCP, but I realized too late that this one camera had the static IP set on the camera's web interface.

I have the MAC address and have tried applying a DHCP reservation for it, but I have confirmed via Wireshark that the IP address is still under the old subnet (192.168.86.x) per the internal settings. What can I do to connect to this device without manually resetting it? The camera is not easily accessible.

Comment: Try powering offthe camerafir a good 10 minutes

Comment: Wired? Then if you have a spare/old small Switch or at least a 2 port Router, plug the camera wire into it, and a pc/laptop in too. Set the network suitable to the old IP. You should now have have an "isolated" network that you can set up to login and change the camera. OR, save you new routers settings, reset it to work with the old IP, then reload your saved settings after.

Comment: How about just connecting it directly to a PC? It if Wi-Fi only? Just temporarily change your PC’s IP address and related network settings. Change the camera to a usable IP on the router, then just correct the IP address on the PC and you should be good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the device is still on the same Ethernet domain as you: temporarily change your own IP address to 192.168.86.x (different from the camera, of course, but still within what the camera considers to be its local subnet).

Your router is not involved in communications between its "LAN" ports (or between a switch's ports), so it won't care that you are using completely different addresses than the router is.

Comment: Thank you! So much easier than I realized it would be.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution will be to modify in your router to support the range
`192.168.86.x` rather than `192.168.0.x`.